# Map of word documents and their URL's

Tags: url, word

Does anybody know of any tools that would allow me to map out all my sharepoint MS Word documents and show the relations they have to each other?

I would like to see for each document, all the docs they reference and all the docs that reference them. I would like to be able to get access to the raw data of these mappings and if possible even see the node/edge sort of map for how they inter-relate.